# I want to save multiple images path to a mysql database using file upload option? I am using a form which inputs other data to the database as well

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

This is my form code:

```html
<form id="AddRoom" action="addRoomdb.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Home Renter User Name</label>
    <input type="email" name="username" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter UserName">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This should be the username given when registering to the site.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Price</label>
    <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Price">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Area</label>
    <input type="text" name="area" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Area">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Available From</label>
    <input type="date" name="availFrom" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Date from which the room is available">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Available To</label>
    <input type="date" name="availTo" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Last date upto which the room is available">
  </div>
   
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleSelect1">Room Type</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name="type">
      <option>Single</option>
      <option>Double</option>
      <option>Triple</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleTextarea">Description of Room</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" name="description" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Photos</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleInputFile" name="image" aria-describedby="fileHelp" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" multiple>
    <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Maximum of 5 photos.</small>
  </div>
  
  
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Room</button>
</form>
</div>
```

This is the addRoom.php page which i use to send the data to the database from the form...

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bnb");
if(!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect');
    }
mysqli_select_db($con, "bnb");

//check values are set
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['area']) && isset($_POST['availFrom']) && isset($_POST['availTo']) && isset($_POST['type']) && isset($_POST['description']) && isset($_POST['image'])){


$UserName =$_POST['username'];
$FirstName =$_POST['firstname'];
$LastName =$_POST['lastname'];
$Price =$_POST['price'];
$Area =$_POST['area'];
$AvailFrom =$_POST['availFrom'];
$AvailTo = $_POST['availTo'];
$Type =$_POST['type'];
$Description =$_POST['description'];
$image =$_POST['image'];
$query = "INSERT INTO bnb.rooms (UserName, FirstName, LastName, Price, Area, AvailFrom, AvailTo, Type, Facilities, Images) VALUES ('" . $UserName . "','" . $FirstName . "','" . $LastName  ."','" . $Price . "','" . $Area . "','" . $AvailFrom . "','" . $AvailTo . "','" . $Type . "','" . $Description . "','" . $image . "')"; //sql query


$result = mysqli_query($con,$query); //execute 


if($result){

    header('location:index.php');
}

mysqli_close($con);
}

?>
```

I have tried many codes but the addRoom.php runs and the image get saved but not the image path from which i have selected... 
can someone pls help...

Comment: you need to store the file in file system and store that path in database

Comment: could u pls explain how with some code

Comment: There are lot's of tutorial for that . do more search on google . i found this one https://www.onlinebuff.com/article_step-by-step-to-upload-an-image-and-store-in-database-using-php_40.html

Answer (score 0):

For store image and save to database you done totally wrong.

**1. Add enctype attribute in form tag**

```
<form id="AddRoom" action="addRoomdb.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**2. Use image name suitable for multiple**

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleInputFile" name="image[]" aria-describedby="fileHelp" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" multiple>
```

Here we changed `name="image"` to `name="image[]"`

**3. Use Global variable `$_FILES` to upload images**

[PHP file upload](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) Tutorial

**4. Now try and upload files for multiple input**

For this many tutorials are available online, or refere below code.

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $j = 0;     // Variable for indexing uploaded image.
    $target_path = "uploads/";     // Declaring Path for uploaded images.
    $_FILES['file'] = $_FILES['image'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
// Loop to get individual element from the array
        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");      // Extensions which are allowed.
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]));   // Explode file name from dot(.)
        $file_extension = end($ext); // Store extensions in the variable.
        $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];     // Set the target path with a new name of image.
        $j = $j + 1;      // Increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array.
        if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000)     // Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
                && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
// If file moved to uploads folder.
                echo $j . ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
            } else {     //  If File Was Not Moved.
                echo $j . ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {     //   If File Size And File Type Was Incorrect.
            echo $j . ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**5. Get file path**

While uploading files you can get file path with file name to store in database